# Change system file temporary maximum age

Tags: 8, files, cron

The default setting given to delete temp files is after 6 hours minimum. I have users upload files and I want that if it has temp status, delete it after 15 secs. Tweaking the file module code is risky, if I get the exact location to change 6 hours to 15 sec that will do the job.

Comment: That also means you need to have a cron job running every 15 seconds. That job then triggers drush cron maybe. Can you maybe paste a link to the exact line of the file module on git.drupalcode.org you identified being responsible for the 6h minimum into your question?

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from `\Drupal::config('system.file')->get('temporary_maximum_age')` is the value that decides when temporary files are deleted. Using the following code, for example, you can change that value to 15 seconds.

```php
\Drupal::config('system.file')->set('temporary_maximum_age', '15');
```

If you want to change the form as well, which is recommended, use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to adjust the system file settings shown in the *system_file_system_settings* form.

The code currently used for that setting is the following one.

```php
$intervals = [0, 21600, 43200, 86400, 604800, 2419200, 7776000];
$period = array_combine($intervals, array_map([$this->dateFormatter, 'formatInterval'], $intervals));
$period[0] = $this->t('Never');
$form['temporary_maximum_age'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Delete temporary files after'),
  '#default_value' => $config->get('temporary_maximum_age'),
  '#options' => $period,
  '#description' => $this->t('Temporary files are not referenced, but are in the file system and therefore may show up in administrative lists. <strong>Warning:</strong> If enabled, temporary files will be permanently deleted and may not be recoverable.'),
];
```

You can alter the form and adjust it to what you need.

Keep in mind that files are effectively deleted after 15 seconds if cron tasks run at least every 15 seconds.

Comment: Thank you @Ziftman, I did the same and changed 21600 to 15 in /core/modules/system/src/Form/FileSystemForm.php and uploaded a new temp file. However, the file was not deleted automatically after 15 seconds. Please tell me what did I miss.

Comment: @PankhuriSingh you should not change the core file, you can override that from your own custom module, and in order to have the file deleted your corn should run at least every 15sec, that's why I told you it makes no sense to do that. in case you really want to do that every 15 sec then you need to do it without depending on cron tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Add to local.settings.php

```
$config['system.file']['temporary_maximum_age'] = 15;
```

Note that the temporary files are deleted on cron , which is settable to 1h minimum through the back office or less using server cron job `https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron/configuring-cron-jobs-using-the-cron-command`